# Is there a way to avoid the strict aliasing warning?

Tags: c++

I'm using a library (ENet), which uses callbacks. In those callback functions, it passes a struct which contains a void* for user data, for your own use. I'd like to use that variable, but not as a pointer. I don't want to allocate memory just so I can point to it, I'd rather use the space of the void* directly to store a size_t.

But, as expected, when I cast the void* variable to a size_t variable, I get a strict alias warning. And the callback's struct doesn't provide a union to access it as something other than a void*.

I know I can disable that warning completely, but I'd rather just silence it for this particular case. Is there a way to write a cast of this sort that lets the compiler know it is intentional, to avoid the warning?

**Edit:**

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do. Since I need to be able to edit the user value, I'm casting it to size_t while also trying to grab a reference to it:

```
size_t& offset = reinterpret_cast<size_t&>(packet->userData);
```

This works, but gives the warning.

Comment: Which language are you working in?

Comment: C++, using a C library

Comment: Do you understand what strict aliasing is?  And why violating it is a bad idea?  Disabling the warning can make your code go crazy: the compiler can assume that no change to a `size_t&` can cause a `void*&` to change, and cache the `void*&` value in a register, ignoring your changes...

Comment: this is C++ code, please remove the 'C' tag

Comment: This seems dangerous.  What if `sizeof(size_t) != sizeof(void*)`?

Comment: My understanding is that size_t is guaranteed to be the size of a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But, as expected, when I dereference the void* variable to a size_t variable, I get a strict alias warning.

If you want to use the `void *` itself just to transport a plain integer, you don't want to dereference it, you want to cast it to an appropriate integral type (`intptr_t` is your best bet, as the standard guarantees that it can survive to a roundtrip through `void *`).

```
intptr_t magic=42;
register_callback(&myfunc, (void *)magic);

// ...

void myfunc(void *context)
{
    intptr_t magic=(intptr_t)context;
    // ...
}
```

(if you like C++-style casts, those would all be `reinterpret_cast`)

Besides, you are probably doing something weird in your code, because `void *` (like `char *` and `unsigned char *`) is not subjected to the strict aliasing rule (they can alias any other pointer).

---

***Update***

> Here is an example of what I'm trying to do. Since I need to be able to edit the user value, I'm casting it to size_t while also trying to grab a reference to it:
>
> ```
> size_t& offset = reinterpret_cast<size_t&>(packet->userData);
> ```
>
> This works, but gives the warning.

Nope, even assuming that `size_t` and `void *` had the same size and alignment requirements (which is not guaranteed), this cannot be done portably; aliasing a `void *&` with a `size_t &` is not allowed (also, this is particularly devious because it's hidden in a reference).

If you really need to do this, you have to come to terms with your compiler; in gcc, for example, you could compile just the file where you have this thing with `-fno-strict-aliasing`, which, instead of simply disabling the warning (=hiding the potential problem under the carpet), disables the compiler assumptions about strict aliasing, so that the generated code works correctly even if pointers/references to unrelated types point to the same stuff.

Comment: Thanks. I mis-typed, I'm doing a cast, not a dereference. I'll update the post to show what I'm actually trying to do, in case it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Knowing that, I edited my code to fetch and update the variable in separate steps rather than using a reference. All good now!